# Array only containing certain type of object

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want an array that can only contain a certain type of object.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: what you want to check? Like it contains string or int . in this way?

Comment: @veelian: i done this before by using the category feature in iOS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do this. An `NSMutableArray` has the `addObject` method, whose parameter is an id and can be any NSObject-based object.

If you want to protect your array from accidently getting populated with bad data from other classes, make it a private ivar and access it using a public @property or method. The public method will check the class of the object that a caller is trying to add to the array before actually calling `addObject`.